# Zusagen plus Dativ

Tags: dative

> Die Anpflanzung der Bäume durch die örtlichen Betriebe ist zugesagt.

Ist der Satz richtig?

Ursprünglich hieß der Satz:

> Örtliche Betriebe sagten zu, Bäume anzupflanzen.

Warum heiß es nicht, der Anpflanzung ... sagten zu?

Comment: Bei der Nominalisierung in den Passiv hat sich ein kleiner Bedeutungsunterschied eingeschlichen. Die örtlichen Betriebe haben nicht zugesagt, dass sie selbst die Bäume anpflanzen würden, nur dass die Bäume angepflanzt würden. Die korrekte Nominalisierung in den Passiv wäre also: `Die Anpflanzung der Bäume ist durch die örtlichen Betriebe zugesagt.`

Comment: Allerdings sagt der aktive Satz in der Tat, dass die Betriebe zugesagt haben, das selbst zu tun (auch wenn das wohl nicht gemeint war). Sonst müsste es heißen: "Örtliche Betriebe sagten zu, Bäume anpflanzen zu lassen".

Comment: Warum überhaupt Dativ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Warum heiß es nicht, der Anpflanzung ... sagten zu?

Weil bei "zusagen" der Dativ anzeigt, wer informiert wird. Ein sinnvolles Beispiel wäre: "Der örtliche Betrieb sagte *dem Gemeinderat* zu, die Anpflanzung noch dieses Jahr fertigzustellen".

Ich finde die ursprüngliche Formulierung ("Örtliche Betriebe sagten zu, Bäume anzupflanzen.") übrigens deutlich eleganter als die Variante mit Substantiv.

Comment: +1 für die Bewertung des grausigen Nominalstils in diesem Beispiel.

Answer (score 1):

- **Verbalstil**

  > Örtliche Betriebe sagten zu, [was? Akk.] Bäume anzupflanzen.
- **Nominalstil**

  > Die Anpflanzung der Bäume durch die örtlichen Betriebe ist zugesagt.
  >   (Was ist [durch die örtlichen Betriebe] zugesagt? Die Anpflanzung der Bäume.)

Here the dative object (`Wem [ist zugesagt]?`) is not determined, so it's kind of a general consent.

Comment: You should check Toscho's comment on the original question. Else, fine answer

Comment: @emanuel interisting. So `Örtliche Betriebe sagten zu, Bäume anzupflanzen.` does not tell *by whom* planting will be performed?

Comment: This does too. It's ambiguous because now there is no "durch" that assigns roles. The way @Toscho did it works  because the "durch"-part comes after the verb. If you have  in front of "ist" then it is part of "die Anpflanzung" and is not an adverb.